# How get combination of sums of numbers in Array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinations

I have an array and i want to get all combination of sums of its number.

```
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
1st iteration : 1+2=3,1+3=4, 1+4=5, 1+5=6
and array becomes arr[1,2,3,4,5,6]
2nd iteration : 2+1=3,2+3=5, 2+4=6, 2+5=7
and array becomes arr[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]......

and 1+2+3=6, 1+2+4=7
.
.
.
and 1+2+3+4=10
.
. 
. 
and 1+2+3+4+5=15
and final array becomes =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,15]
```

Can anyone help me to build an algo for this?

Here is what i have tried so far, I tried to prepare array of possible sub arrays of arr but could not get all combination.

```
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
    let a=[];
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; j < arr.length; j++){
            let b=[];
            for( let k=i; k<=j; k++ ){
                b.push(arr[k]);
            }
            a.push(b);

        }
    }
    console.log(a);
```

Comment: please add the code, you tried.

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you've tried so far so the community can help you

Comment: `to get all combination of sums of its number.` Your iterations does not perform all the combinations, they just sums the first element with the nth element of the array.

Comment: A **6 year** old active member of StackOverflow must know, that you should provide some code of what you have attempted to achieve the desire result.

Comment: How did you get 15? It seemed to be simple till then.

Comment: *1+2+4=6* - how (line 7)?

Comment: @rv7, it was a typo

Comment: @NitinPawar, 1+2+3+4+5=15

Comment: What about 2+3+4+5=14 and 1+3+4+5=13 and 1+2+4+5=12? Any reason you're skipping those?

Comment: @m69, no i am not skipping these, i want all these combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary or associative array (which JavaScript's arrays are) to store which sums can be made, by using the sum as the index and setting the element to 'true', similar to creating a sieve; you can then iterate over this sparse array efficiently with `for in`.

```js
function sums(values) {
    var dictionary = [];
    for (var i in values) {
        var temp = [values[i]];               // start with value by itself
        for (var j in dictionary) {
            temp.push(values[i] + Number(j)); // sum of value and values already in dictionary
        }
        for (var k in temp) {
            dictionary[temp[k]] = true;       // transfer values to dictionary
        }
    }
    var output = [];
    for (var i in dictionary) {
        output.push(Number(i));               // convert dictionary to array of values
    }
    return output;
}
document.write(sums([2,5,11,16]));
```